# R: Select rows in which at least half of the columns satisfy a certain condition

Tags: r

I have this problem I am simply not able to figure out. I imported a table into R which has 20 columns and around 20,000 rows. The columns have numeric values. I was wondering how I could only select the rows in which at least half the columns have a value greater than 20. To explain clearly, I only want to select the rows in which at least 10 columns have a value greater than 20.

I know how to select rows in which any one column has to have a value greater than 20. For that, I used this code:

```
    y=Table[apply(Table[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) any(x > 20)), ]
```

Is there any way to do the same such that at least half the columns have a value greater than 20?

Thanks!

Comment: Very close to a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145625/how-to-filter-out-matrix-rows-with-entries-less-than-specific-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your approach we could just use a different function instead of `any()`

```
y=Table[apply(Table[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) {sum(x>20)*2 >= length(x)}), ]
```

============== EDIT ================

Simpler and faster would be to avoid `apply()`.

```
Y <- Table[rowSums(Table > 20) >= 10,]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to test it on my dataset. Would you be kind enough to explain the second part of the function? Thanks a lot though!

Comment: X>20 is a vector of T/F.  When we take the sum of it that T become 1 and F become 0, we get the number of elements in X that are greater than 20.  It's a single number.  We want to know if that number is greater than half the length of X (which is the number of columns).  If it is, then 2 times that number will be greater than the length of X.  Is that what you were asking about?  Remember that X here is a single row of Table. You could also use `sum(x>20)>10` if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Yes, that is what I was asking about. I wanted to select the rows in which at least half the columns had a value greater than 20.